# TS2551: TS:2339 Problem with dynamic adding key/value to existing object (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript

I have class which create new instances of some classes and attach their by key to `this.data` property. It goings only through the constructor of `SuperClass`.

But if I want to add to `this.data` using `dynamicAddToData` method of `SuperClass` then TypeScript says me that this property is not exist.

I guess generics can solve my problem, but possibly not to use generics?

```
declare type SuperClassData<M> = {
  [K in keyof M]: M[K]
}

declare type SuperClassConstructorObject<M> = {
  [K in keyof M]: (new () => M[K])
}

class SuperClass<MP> {
  public data: SuperClassData<MP> = {} as SuperClassData<MP>

  constructor (obj: SuperClassConstructorObject<MP>) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
      const Class = obj[key]
      this.data[key] = new Class()
    }
  }

  public dynamicAddToData (key: string, Class: any): void {
    this.data[key] = new Class()
  }
}

class Foo {
  public foo = () => 'foo'
}

class Bar {
  public bar = () => 'bar'
}

const superClass = new SuperClass({ foo: Foo, bar: Bar })

superClass.dynamicAddToData('baz', Bar)

superClass.data.bar.bar() // bar
superClass.data.baz.bar()
```

[image]
Property 'baz' does not exist on type 'SuperClassData<{ foo: Foo; bar: Bar; }>'.ts(2339)

Will be glad each answer

Comment: I dont think it is possible this way, 
where you initialised the SuperClass object with a json object, the keys on that object are the only keys you can access.
keyof is a very nice addition to TS that allows enumeration of a types keys very quickly and combined like this you can restrict data programmatically at compile time to ensure your objects are safe and cant have whatever values you choose

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html

Comment: cont.. if you didnt have keyof you should be able to make this work, as your "data" property would just a standard dictionary / object whose key would be whatever you specified as "key"

Comment: @Sohan thanks for your answer, I will continue trying to solve this problem using `keyof`. Hope it can helps to me. Thanks!

Comment: Sure if you get something let us know. And if you are happy with my comment please vote for it.